# ruby on rails - 1 error prohibited this listing from being saved: Image has contents that are not what they are reported to be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

1 error prohibited this listing from being saved:
Image has contents that are not what they are reported to be

That's the error that I get when I try to upload a picture for a listing. I've tried various types of validations and nothing is working.

This is what my **Model** looks like.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb =>"100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
    validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
end
```

Can someone please explain to me what I did wrong, and what I can do to fix it. I really want to keep working on this application but I've hit a problem!

Comment: For most accurate answers, please include the gem you use for images (I'm guessing `paperclip`), action that threw an error, and the form used.

Comment: are you using any gem (e.g. `carrierwave`, `paperclip`) for uploading file?

Comment: The first thing i would always do in a situation like this is search the source code of the gem for that error message.  Then you will see what conditions it tests in order to fail this validation.

Comment: Yes I am using paperclip.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the following

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

Also make sure that you are indeed uploading images with the mentioned extensions

Comment: Still no luck, I don't know why it wouldn't work with your help. It says that it is a different content, but the image that I'm uploading is jpeg, and i'm validating jpeg in my code?

Comment: What happens when you remove the validation code part ?

Comment: If I take out the validation part I get the following error: "Paperclip::Errors:MissingRequiredValidatorError". :( I've skipped this part of my application, and hope to fix the error.

Comment: This is weird, when I launched my site the uploading works. It seems when my app is live it lets the image update, but when I'm local it doesnt, weird.

Comment: IT must be due to some missing packages on ur local machine , if you are on ubuntu then you need Imagemagick or Rmagick to upload .

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused because you don't have `file` program (probably you don't use Unix system?)

`file` is used by paperclip to check whether sent file is what it should be or not (based on your validator).

If you are on Windows, you should manually download and install [file for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) and add it to either

- Windows PATH environment variable,
- project environments (`config/environments/development.rb`, add line `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '{your_path_to_dir_with_file/bin}'` )

After that, restart console, server and it should work.

Comment: Your solution works for me. I am using windows 10, ruby 2.2.3 and rails 4.2.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what you can do only for windows** :

- Install the exe by
- download the exe from this link [file.exe](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)
- test if is well installed by running your cmd and put the following instructions  `convert logo: logo.miff` then run ' *imdisplay logo.miff* '
  you will get custom logo image,that will pop up on your windows screen.

From here now you can start configuring everything on rails app

1. Open `config/environments/development.rb`

   2. Add the following line: `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'`
   3. If your rails server is currently running,brake the server and then run again rails s.After that you should be ready to go.Upload image on your app